# Can't return a set

Tags: clojure

I am trying to get an set out of this code, but I am getting an exception:

```
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/get-non-friends-set (form-init1338839880564085393.clj:7).
clojure.core$set cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection
```

Here is my code:

```
    (defn get-non-friends-set [id]
      (let [non-friends set]
        (doseq [i (get-friends-set id)]
          (doseq [j (get-friends-set i)]
            (if (and (false? (is-friend? j id))
                     (false? (is-privacy-on? j)))
              (conj non-friends j)
              non-friends)))))
```

The logic is working, if I replace the `(conj non-friends j)` to `(println j)`, I got the `(j)` output I am expecting, but I need the function to return a set.

Comment: Just to elaborate on Alan's bold suggestion: `doseq` doesn't return a usable value; it's meant to carry out side effects. Instead of `doseq`, you should be using `loop` or `reduce` if you want the loop to evaluate to a value. Imperative constructs like `doseq` should be avoided when you're first starting out as they don't encourage proper FP practice. They're make code harder to read and write if used improperly.

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/6e7ca32b506ae36835e39feb119ee22d). If I were you, I'd split the inner reduction off into its own function, but that's a personal choice. You're just going to need to get used to returning transformed data instead of trying to mutate the data in place like you're trying to do here. `conj` does not change it's argument; it returns new, altered data.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for that clarification on doseq. Your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like `for` would be right tool to use

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to return a function, instead of invoking the function and returning the result.  You need `(hash-set)` instead of `set` - note the parens & the name change.

However, it often shorter & clearer to just write a literal empty set as `#{}` instead of invoking the function:

```
(let [non-friends #{} ] 
   ...)
```

vs

```
(let [non-friends (hash-set) ] 
   ...)
```

However, you have another problem in that **your 2 `doseq` loops will both always return `nil`**.  You probably want to use the `filter` or `filterv` function instead.

See

- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter)
- https://www.braveclojure.com/
- Books like `Getting Clojure`, `Living Clojure`

Comment: I see, but I've done that before. In that case I get only nil as result. The `(conj non-friends j)`  doesn't seem to be working. And still, if I change it to `(println j)` I am still getting the logic correctly.

Comment: Notice the bold part, and the suggestion.

Comment: And perhaps check [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for). E.g., `(for [i (get-friends-set id) j (get-friends-set i)] [i j])`. For is like `doseq` but then with return values.